# Have both proprietary drivers and open source drivers at the same time

Tags: gpu-driver

I recently reinstalled ubuntu (after switching back to windows for a few months) and remember needed both sets of drivers for various games and programs. From what I remember there was a line of code that prevented both from existing at the same time, which I removed to fix my issue. How do I fix this problem? I'm also okay with any simpler or new fixes to this problem, so any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you've installed the proprietary drivers correctly, the file to disable nouveau (the open source Nvidia driver included in Ubuntu) is in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf
```

or on your system it might be

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

The line that disables nouveau is

```
blacklist nouveau
```

However, you may also need/have the following lines:

```
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Removing those line[s] should allow nouveau to run.

Now that I've answered your question, I'm going to give you some advice: *do not do this*. There is a very small chance you will get the GUI to work at all if you re-enable nouveau while you have the proprietary drivers installed. They are not designed to be run side-by-side. In addition, I cannot think of any situation in which you are required to use nouveau and not the proprietary driver. Any situation where nouveau runs, the proprietary driver should as well - and the proprietary driver will work in all the areas that nouveau does not.

I'm not entirely sure what you remember, but my personal recommendation is if you play any games or do anything with graphics, just use the proprietary driver. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches and time.